# Checkbox inside ngx bootstrap accordion header not working properly

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, accordion, ngx-bootstrap

I have a checkbox inside the accordian header like below

```
    <accordion-group class="container-fluid"
      *ngFor="let header of data.premiseMeters; let i = index" (isOpenChange)="fetchMeterHistory($event)">
      <div class="row" accordion-heading>
          <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="header.isChecked" class="form-check-input" (click)="checkboxClick()" > 
          <label class="form-check-label" for="check"></label>
        <span class="w20">MP Number: {{header.mp}}</span>
        <span class="w20"> ID: {{header.id}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="accordian-inner-content">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr class="meter-reading-header">
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">reading</th>
              <th scope="col">type</th>
              <th scope="col">usage</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of readingHistory" class="meter-reading-content">
              <td>{{data.date}} </td>
              <td>{{data.reading}}</td>
              <td>{{data.type}}</td>
              <td>{{data.usage}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

Below is the function i am calling while clicking in the checkbox which will prevent the propagation from the checkbox.

```
    checkboxClick(header, $event){
        console.log('Checked state: ' + header.checked);
        $event.stopPropagation();
      }
```

Unfortunately when i click on the checkbox it is not changing the value.
header.checked is having a boolean value which i am getting from a service call response. I am not quite understanding what am i doing wrong here.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed that in HTML you have `[(ngModel)]="header.isChecked"` whereas in TS you have `header.checked`. Is this intentionally different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `(click)="checkboxClick()"` and then

```
checkboxClick(header, $event){
         ...
        $event.stopPropagation();
      }
```

you are overriding the binding here `[(ngModel)]="header.isChecked"`.

Try changing it to

```
checkboxClick(header, $event){
         ...
        header.checked = ! header.checked
        $event.stopPropagation();
      }
```